# The reversibility of matrix multiplication problem in a proof by indution question about matrix raised to the nth power

Tags: matrices, proof-explanation

Sorry if the question is phrased in a clumsy way. I would definitely appreciate any help to make it clearer.
[image]

This is a question from A-Level Further Math (Cambridge Internation Edition)

Searchable Version:

> Consider the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$. It is given that $A^n=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\n&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Proof:

> Let $P_k$ be the statement that, for some value $n=k$, $A^k=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\k&1\end{pmatrix}$. To show this result is true, we must show the first case is true. This is achieved by considering $A^1=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$, which is true. Hence $P_1$ is true.
> Then consider $A^kA$, which is $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\k&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\k+1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$ So it is true that $P_k\Rightarrow P_{k+1}$. Since $P_1$ is true and $P_{k} \Rightarrow P_{k+1}$, by the principle of mathematical induction, $P_n$ is true for all for all $n\geqq1$.

The problem with this proof is why are we trying to prove $A^{k+1}=A^k\cdot A$ instead of trying to prove $A\cdot A^k$, I realize the result is the same, but I am can't help but feeling a little confused as to what $A^{k+1}$ means, especially in light of the non-conversability of matrix multiplication.

Comment: $A$ commutes with itself, so $AA^k = A^kA$.

Comment: $A^k$ is just the product of $k$ $A$s.

Comment: In the absence of brackets, matrix multiplication is generally done from right to left.

Comment: surely you mean from right to left？

Comment: It might help to think of multiplying matrices as a series of function compositions. Then multiplying matrices is associative because the order of the compositions is the same.  For more on what I mean, check out this [3B1B video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkY2DOUCWMU).

Answer (score 1):

In a set with a non-associative operation, powering becomes problematic from $A^3$ onwards;
is $A^3=A^2A=(AA)A$ or is it $AA^2=A(AA)$? If we don't know that $(AA)A$ and $A(AA)$ are the same then we're stuck.

But matrix multiplication is associative and this problem doesn't arise. If multiplication
is associative then there are two ways to potentially define powering recursively.

(i) $A^1=A$ and $A^{n+1}=A^nA$, and

(ii) $A^1=A$ and $A^{n+1}=AA^n$.

Whichever way you choose you can prove $A^mA^n=A^{m+n}$ by induction, and so that
your definition is equivalent to the other one.